# ASUS X556UB Windows 10 touchpad issue

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

This seems to be a common error, but none of the proposed solutions online worked.

The computer is an [ASUS X556UB](https://www.asus.com/hu/Laptops/X556UB/).
The error is supposedly caused by Windows Update installing wrong drivers for the touchpad. I received the machine after the fact, I cannot see this driver in update history, so it could be that a lot of time passed since that.

The error symptoms:

- **Touchpad does not work.**
- Fn+F9 does not turn it on.
- *Touchpad is not listed under Device Manager*/Mice and other pointing device
- Something is listed under HID, called "I2C HID Device", and it has a little exclamation mark and an error message "A request for the HID descriptor failed".

The proposed solutions, that did not help, include:

- Installing the latest drivers linked from the [product page](https://www.asus.com/hu/Laptops/X556UB/HelpDesk_Download/)

  - ATK Package 1.0.0050
  - Asus Smart Gesture / Touchpad Driver 4.0.12
- Installing the even latester drivers linked from [a third-party page](http://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10/) (the links still point to ASUS servers):

  - ATK Package 1.0.0053
  - Asus Smart Gesture / Touchpad Driver 4.0.18

**What should I do to make my touchpad work again?**

Comment: Did you try to update the I2C HID Device drivers using those of the touchpad?

Comment: You could also try to install the Synaptics Windows 10 I2C drivers: [link](http://www.synaptics.com/resources)

Comment: @spike_66 I managed to install the drivers from a subfolder called either `Elan_PTP` or `Focaltech_PTP` (the ones with I2C in the name didn't install). The error from the HID device disappears but the touchpad still doesn't work.